# Cerrar shell de python al salir de una aplicación Kivy

Tags: python, shell, kivy

Al cerrar una aplicación en kivy mediante el siguiente fragmento de código en kivy:

```
Button:
    id: button7
    text: "Salir"
    on_release: menu.save(), app.stop()
```

Sigo teniendo estas dos pantallas:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
¿Hay algún código para cerrar la Shell de Python que pueda incluir en mi app, para que al pulsar el botón de salir, se cierren las dos pantallas que me aparecen?
¿Hay algún código que pueda incluir en mi app para cerrar solo la pantalla negra (entiendo que es la correspondiente a kivy)?

Answer (score 3):

La ventana de la izquierda es una consola interactiva del entorno de desarrollo, el IDLE. Esta ventana aparece porque estas ejecutando tu código desde el IDLE, en condiciones normales de uso ejecutarias la app llamando al intérprete directamente y este mostrará una instancia de la consola de Windows o terminal. En este último caso la consola se cierra al cerrar la app de forma automática.

Tu problema es que **estas ejecutando el script desde el propio IDLE** y no desde la consola de Windows. Si lo ejecutas desde la consola o haciendo doble click sobre `main.py` (si tienes correctamente configurada tu PATH) el código que presentas funciona perfectamente:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string('''
<MyWidget>:
    Button:
        text: 'cerrar'
        on_release: app.stop()
        '''
    )

class MyWidget(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__()

class myApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyWidget()

if __name__ in ('__main__'):
    myApp().run()
```

Es problema del IDLE y su consola interactiva no de Kivy.

No obstante en las interfaces gráficas una vez terminada su desarrollo lo que se suele querer es que no se invoque a la consola sino que solo aparezca la interfaz solamente. En windows lo que se hace es cambiar la extensión del módulo python de `.py` a `.pyw`. Esto ocasiona que el archivo sea ejecutado por `pythonw.exe` en vez de por `python.exe`:

- **python.exe** es una aplicación de consola para ejecutar scripts de tipo CLI (comand line interface). Cuando ejecutas en Windows un script python (con doble click sobre él o llamando al intérprete desde una terminal) python.exe abre una nueva consola (o se ejecuta en la que lo hemos lanzadfo en el segundo caso) y `sys.stdin`, `sys.stdout` and `sys.stderr` son redirigidas hacia esta.

  Si la consola es creada nueva automáticamente (no lanzamos el script manualmente desde una consola) esta permanece abierta hasta que termine la ejecución del script (correcta o con errores). Si el script ha sido invocado desde una consola existente esta queda bloqueada hasta que el script termine.

  La ejecución es síncrona en todo momento.
- **pythonw.exe** en cambio es una GUI. Al igual que el anterior permite lanzar scripts de Python y generalmente es usado para las las interfaces gráficas de usuario donde la interacccion con la app se realiza mediante la interfaz y no por la consola. 
  En este caso no se abre una consola de windows (CMD) al ejecutar el script. Esto implica que no están disponibles `sys.stdin`, `sys.stdout` y `sys.stderr`.

  La ejecución es asíncrona en este caso.

Si quieres ejecutar tu GUI sin que aparezca la consola renombra tu script a `main.pyw` en Windows. En Linux el procedimiento es distinto.