# Como ocultar la ventana cmd al abrir un programa en tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Me preguntaba como ocultar la ventana de cmd que se crea al abrir mi programa en tkinter.

A esto me refiero:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden ver atrás de la ventana de tkinter se abre una de cmd.

Como puedo ocultarla?

Comment: Simplemente renombra tu módulo principal de `main.py` a `main.pyw`, al final de esta respuesta hay una explicación más detallada: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/64748/15089

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simplemente guárdelo con una extensión `.pyw`.

**Esto evitará que se abra la ventana de la consola.**